# Will NXP NFC PN532 work connected to an antenna grid that is multiplexed?

Tags: antenna, rfid, nfc

Can I operate say 36 different antenna monitoring tags against a grid of small 2" x 2" squares by simply connecting the antenna to something like the [NXP NFC PN532](http://www.nxp.com/documents/short_data_sheet/PN532_SDS.pdf) through a multiplexer (N-to-1 multiplexer)? Does such a scheme work? If yes, how long will each antenna need to be multiplexed in before a reading can be obtained?

Comment: Could you please link to a AN532 datasheet? From your question it isn't even clear what it's supposed to be. (Frankly when I see "AN532" I think Application Note.)

Comment: Datasheet: http://www.nxp.com/documents/short_data_sheet/PN532_SDS.pdf

Comment: Duh that should have been PN, not AN.

Comment: Karrthik's link seems broken. I think he is referring to https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/nxp/data-sheets/PN532_C1.pdf

Comment: Also while not an answer. You may want to check https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa167/sloa167.pdf which is an example of a RFID Multiplexer Example System using a TRF7960A NFC reader IC. Key thing is that it's using an RF switch. So if your NFC antenna is single ended then you only need a single input mux, but if dual then I think you need a dual mux. But key thing is it has to been an RF switch like PE42440 and PE4257 in the examples above.